# How to do these type of questions without graphs

Tags: functions

> The function $f:[0,3]\to[1,29]$ is defined by $$f(x)=2x^3-15x^2+36x+1$$

**Then the function is**

$1.$ one one and onto

$2.$ onto but not one one

$3.$ one one but not onto

$4.$ neither one one nor onto

---

The way I know to approach these type of questions is using a rough hand drawn graph. But I can't graph this function by hand.

Is there any way to do these types of questions in general without a graph$?$ This is just one question, I'm facing problems in many questions like these$?$

Please tell me the method if there's any. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you allowed to use a calculator?

Comment: @callculus42 What for?

Comment: @AnotherUser To calculate  $f(3)$, for instance.

Comment: you really can draw this by hand, and the practice is good for you.  First find the values at the integers involved, $x=0,1,2,3$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since
$$
f'(x)=6x^2-30x+36=6(x-2)(x-3),
$$
you know that $f'(x)<0$ when $x\in(2,3)$ and that $f'(x)>0$ when $x\in[0,2)$. Therefore, $f$ is strictly increasing on $[0,2]$ and strictly decreasing on $[2,3]$. So, $\max f=f(2)=29$. Besides, since $f(0)=1$ and $f(3)=28$, the range of $f$ is $[1,29]$. Therefore, the correct choice is the second one.

Comment: The correct answer is **onto but not one one** as given in the solution

Comment: That is correct. I had read $[0,29]$ instead of $[1,29]$.

Comment: Can you please add some more details like why you did this and how is the increasing or decreasing nature deciding whether it's one one or not or onto or not?

Comment: I understood why it's not one one..pls explain for onto

Comment: Since $f(0)=1$ and $f(2)=29$, it follows from the intermediate value theorem the every number from $[1,29]$ must belong to the range of $f$.

Comment: I haven't learnt ivt yet..but by logic i think I'm understanding..but pls add some details

Comment: Thanks...I understood by logic